# How do I texture paint on the surfaces after I added an image texture and tiled it using UV unwrapping?

Tags: texture-painting

[image: This object was made using 4 different textures after UV unwrapping it.]

I want to texture paint on the surfaces without affecting the textures already set up. If I create a new texture of 1024x1024px size and start texture painting, I notice that blender draws on all the different 'tiles' of the texture that has been applied previously to the surface.

[image]

If I straight up go to texture painting and start painting on the surface, this is what happens.

Answer (score 1):

Create this kind of node setup, 1 being a b&w mask that you need to paint in order to separate texture 2 and 3, plug 1 into the factor of the *Mix Shader*, paint 3:

[image]

And as pointed out by Gorgious, "you can also initialize texture 3 (painted on) with all pixels set to alpha = 0 and use the alpha output as a mask instead of an aditional mask texture".

Comment: You can also initialize texture 3 (painted on) with all pixels set to alpha = 0 and use the alpha output as a mask instead of an aditional mask texture

Comment: I did that and it still paints on separate tiles of the texture instead of the whole face. https://ibb.co/X4GtvNc

Comment: it depends on how you've unwrapped your mesh I guess